# Commentform input area issue

Tags: comment-form

This is probably really simple, but I just can't figure it out.
So I change the input form on my comment form php.
The changed snipped looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/3Mj1XHGJ

Yet when somebody doesn't click on "Website" at all, still a "http://Website" link will be generated for some. Is there any way to make it so that there won't be any url display if they haven't inserted a website url at all?
Right now only when I click on the "Website input" textarea and make the "Website" text actually disappear it works.

(The following is just a side question and I'm also not sure if it's okay to ask this, so you might as well ignore this):
I also wanted to insert little icons in front of the text (before Website, Mail etc.)
I know how to do it (just as background image using the stylesheet), but I'm already using a background image and I was wondering if there's another way round as using two background images won't work. Probably I have to rewrite the comment.php a bit instead, but I don't think it's possible to insert a "img src" into the input command?

My website is [here](http://www.zoomingjapan.com).

Thanks a lot in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the code to the comment-template.php file located in wp-includes, right under the

```
function get_comment_author_link( $comment_ID = 0 ) {
/** @todo Only call these functions when they are needed. Include in if... else blocks */
$url    = get_comment_author_url( $comment_ID );
$author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID );

if ( empty( $url ) || 'http://' == $url )
    $return = $author;
else
    $return = "<a href='$url' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>$author</a>";
return apply_filters('get_comment_author_link', $return);
}
```

so that the final result looks like this:

```
function get_comment_author_link( $comment_ID = 0 ) {
/** @todo Only call these functions when they are needed. Include in if... else blocks */
$url    = get_comment_author_url( $comment_ID );
$author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID );

if ( empty( $url ) || 'http://' == $url )
    $return = $author;
else
    $return = "<a href='$url' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>$author</a>";
return apply_filters('get_comment_author_link', $return);
}
add_filter('pre_comment_author_url', 'filter_comment_url');
function filter_comment_url($url){
if ($url == "Website" || $url == "http://Website"){
    $url = '';
}
return $url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help. I tried, but it didn't work. Actually now the comment of a person will only be posted if they also enter a website, if not the comment won't go through. I deleted the snippet again, but the error now still occurs. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `pre_comment_author_url` filter hook to clear the url if its Website :

```
add_filter('pre_comment_author_url', 'filter_comment_url');
function filter_comment_url($url){
    if ($url == "Website" || $url == "http://Website"){
        $url = '';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

as for images/icons its strictly a CSS issue and FYI you can simply insert the icons as html img tags.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I added the filter hook into my function.php, but I still have exactly the same problem?!

Comment: Hello! I'm still desperately looking for a solution. The one above didn't work for me. I put it into my function.php, was that correct? Do I have to add anything else to my comment.php, too? Please help. Thanks

Comment: This is an example!!! Change the case specific to match yours and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete beginner, so I'm not sure which of these I actually CAN change. Thanks.

Comment: create a pastebin with your code so we could see and help beter

Comment: Hello. I already pasted the code in the original post, but here's a larger excerpt of it once again: http://pastebin.com/Sqk6LZSL Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: @Bainternet don't you want to run that check on `pre_process_comment` hook, after the comment form is submitted? The `pre_comment_author_url` fires when the form is *generated*, not when it is *submitted*.